# How does count work in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, count

I understand how the method "count" works, from [The string count() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600574/the-string-count-method).

But I can't understand how it's counting words (rather than letter) in arrays:

```
def find_frequency(sentence, word)
  sentence.downcase.split.count(word.downcase)
end

find_frequency("to be or not to be", "to") # => 2
  # same as ["to", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be"].count("to")
"hello world".count("lo") # => 5
```

If `"hello world".count("lo")` returns five, why doesn't `find_frequency("to be or not to be", "to")` return seven (t, o, o, o, t, t, o)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/count), `count(p1)` for `Array`

> Returns the number of elements. If an argument is given, counts the number of elements which equals to obj. If a block is given, counts the number of elements yielding a true value.

In your case, `sentence.downcase.split` gives you `["to", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be"]`. Here, you have two array elements equaling `"to"`, that's why you obtain `2`.

From the [documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/count) of `String`, `count(*args)`

> Each other_str parameter defines a set of characters to count. The intersection of these sets defines the characters to count in str. Any other_str that starts with a caret (^) is negated. The sequence c1–c2 means all characters between c1 and c2.

If we put aside the negation case, given a `String` parameter **p**, call `count` on a `String` **x** returns the number of characters in **x** matching one of the characters of **p**.

In your case, you have `"llool"` in `"hello world"` matching `"lo"`, i.e. `5`